# Brief code example to upload image from iPhone to ImageShack account

Tags: iphone, objective-c, upload, jpeg, imageshack

I'm trying to upload a jpg image from my iPhone to my ImageShack.com account.

Everyone says to use the MASSIVE *THOUSANDS* of lines of code in the 3rd party ASI code.

Is there a simple example, just of the upload code?  (I'll take either sync or async)

Shouldn't this be doable with under 25 lines of code?

Thanks.